# Strategy in a blocking game

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

In this blocking game for 2 is there a clear strategy for the first player, the second player or neither?

You have a 5 x 5 grid of squares. The players take turns laying dominoes so as to cover a pair of adjacent squares. The last to be able to do so is the winner. (As readers can confirm, if 1 or 5 isolated squares remain at the end, the second player has won; if 3 or 7, the first.)

All I've been able to establish is that, if they play haphazardly, there is a greater probability of a win for the first player.

Paul Stephenson

Comment: "Neither" is definitely not the correct answer, since this is a finite game (it's over after at most $12$ moves) and there is no tie.

Comment: @paul what do you mean with "clear strategy" ?

Comment: Dear Arthur,For clear

Comment: Dear Arthur,For 'clear strategy' just read 'strategy'. I meant from the off (as there is for the second player in the 4 x 4 game).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an impartial game with a normal play, every position has a Sprague-Grundy value. If it is 0, it is a win for the previous player. Otherwise, it is a win for the next player.

Indeed, this game is called cram. The Sprague-Grundy value of the 5x5 board is 0. Thus, the second player will always have a winning strategy.

Comment: Thank you S. Pek. I didn't know any of that. I need to do some homework.